# has_many :through name suggestions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have three models, user, achievement, badge and I plan on using has_many :through instead of has_many_and_belongs_to since I will have a few extra fields in the join tables.

According to a Railscast I watched, using this method requires coming up with new model names and not user_badge or user_achievement.

For my User Achievement join what do you think of Accomplishment?

For my User Badge join what do you think of Distinction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is perfect.  It reads as "User has_many Achievements through Accomplishment"